# "book an appointment" in a more casual way

Tags: expressions, british-english, questions

I'd like to ask what would be the most casual/common way for you to book an appointment for a haircut. Let's say I've been to one particular hairdresser several times already and "Can I book an appointment with you tomorrow" sound a bit official to me (maybe I'm wrong here though). What other phrase can I use?

All I can think about is "can I sign up for tomorrow" or "do you have a free place for tomorrow"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try, 'can I have a slot for tomorrow?'

Comment: that's a good one! thx

Comment: "Can you fit me in  tomorrow" or "could you fit me in tomorrow" or "can you do me tomorrow".  I think beginning with "can you" rather than "can I" is more informal and friendly.

Comment: 'Can I book an appointment for tomorrow, please?' **is** probably the most common way and is not going to sound over-formal/over-formulaic (unless you phone every week). The staff don't bother to make a note of 'register' (unless you're rude), just name and date.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned earlier, I'm looking for something less formal just because I have really friendly relationship with my barber i.e. he welcomes me with "what's up mate" and so on...

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: "Can you put me down for tomorrow, about 2PM?"

Comment: meaning "down the list" or is this simply just such an expression?

Comment: "Put me down", in this context, means "write my appointment on your calendar", at least in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks put me down sounds fine for the hairdresser, but perhaps best avoided at the veterinaries.. .

Comment: @davidlol - Also your irritating brother-in-law.

Comment: I rarely ***book*** an appointment,  but I often ***make*** one, or ***get*** one.   "I was hoping to get an appointment tomorrow..." is my go-to phrase for a more casual exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Can I book an appointment with you tomorrow?" sounds fine. I've thought of a few phrases to replace it, but they all either sound equally formal, or like you might be trying to hit on the person.

e.g.

> What times do you have available for tomorrow

or

> Can I come by tomorrow?

Answer (score 0):

I like your original phrasing as the formality actually does loan appropriate detachment, dignifies you as a  speaker and also reinforces the idea that you regard the other person as a professional who in fact has bookings, appointments, clientele. To this last point, too much informality could come across as condescending or that you otherwise disregard the professional character of the individual.

I am sure your concern is borne of empathy, so I will add that he or she will likely *feel* more complimented by being taken seriously and even cause them to take some pride in the job she or he did as it will have merited a comment of esteem (ever-so-subtly) rather than one of placation.

This statement can be a sort of parenthesis within an otherwise casual, warm conversation., i.e. a moment of earnest artistic appreciation.

Otherwise, I also agree with the posters who have all offered the humble questions along the lines of "Can I", "Could you fit me in" as long as that is the precise sentiment you want to express. You might not, on the other hand, be inclined enough toward gratitude as to make the individual feel too very much in demand- from a negotiating perspective ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I "book an appointment" with my stylist:

> Hi Toni.
>   This is Clare. Do you have any openings tomorrow?

or:

> Do you have any openings on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc?

It's quite informal, but I've been seeing the same stylist for over ten years and there's no need for small talk or formality. The small talk can come during the appointment!